# Initial Permutation of DES

Tags: des

I'm implementing DES, but I cannot understand example.

> **Plaintext**: 123456ABCD132536
>   **After initial permutation**: 14A7D67818CA18AD

Plaintext is 64-bits hexadecimal, so each character is 4-bits. The first entry 
 of IP(Initial Permutation) table is 58 which means 58-th binary number in the plaintext.

That number is 1 because 58-th binary number is in 3 which is before the last entry 6. Anyway, it means first binary number in plaintext after IP must be 1!

Then, how can 1 is appeared? First hex must be `1***` and it means greater than equal to 8!! What I'm wrong with this?

Comment: Without even looking at DES: hexadecimals are here used to represent the binary input block. That one hexadecimal digit equals 4 bits (a nibble) is information that is unlikely to be used in the description of DES itself. Block ciphers operate on bits (commonly grouped as 8 bit bytes or "words" of a particular size - 16, 32 or 64 bits - for practical purposes).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [DES specification](https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/publications/fips/46/3/archive/1999-10-25/documents/fips46-3.pdf#page=15) numbers bits form 1 to 64, in reading order of big-endian data.

Bit 58 belongs to the second rightmost hex digit of the plaintext, which contains bits 57 to 60. This hex digit is `3`, that is `0011` in binary, and bit 58 is the second `0` in that.